# Renaming an index that has square brackets in the name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created an index with `[]` in its name so when I look at `sys.indexes` I see it listed literally as `[IX_ValidationCurationTimeStampUTC]`.

When I try renaming it with `sp_rename` like so:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'data.Ops_ValidationCuration.[IX_ValidationCurationTimeStampUTC]', 'IX_ValidationCurationTimeStampUTC', 'INDEX'
```

I receive the error:

> Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 326 [Batch
>   Start Line 20] Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the
>   claimed @objtype (INDEX) is wrong.

If I try without the `INDEX` I receive this error:

> Msg 15225, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 436 [Batch
>   Start Line 20] No item by the name of
>   'data.Ops_ValidationCuration.[IX_ValidationCurationTimeStampUTC]'
>   could be found in the current database 'MyDB', given that @itemtype
>   was input as '(null)'.

I would rather not do the rename manually since it's on 60 different databases.

Any idea about what I could try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run this string through `QUOTENAME` it returns:

```
[[IX_ValidationCurationTimeStampUTC]]]
```

That is what you need to use!

```
EXEC sp_rename 'whatever.[[IX_ValidationCurationTimeStampUTC]]]', 'IX_ValidationCurationTimeStampUTC', 'INDEX'
```